# Capture Value of Type Lookup In Winform

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, csom

I have a field called `Monitoring System` that has a type of `lookup` in my Sharepoint 2010 list.  I want to use C# windows form to return the data for this field, and I tried

```
foreach (ListItem listItem in items)
{
    var ms = listItem["MonitorSys"];
}
```

However, when I look in the immediate window this is what I see

> Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client.FieldLookupValue
>   LookupID: 138
>   LookupValue: "Manderin Villa Services"
>   TypeId: "{xkllkjasdkfjlasfd}"

it looks like what I want is the `LookupValue` but how do I extract that? using CSOM

I tried this syntax, but when it hits my variable assignment it immediately loads the win form and stepping through the code with F11 it does the same...

```
FieldUserValue monsys = (FieldUserValue)listItem["MonitoringSystem"];
string msys = monsys.LookupValue;
```

Full code is:

```
Public static void GetSPData()
{
  using (var ctx = new ClientContext(SPURL))
  {
    List list = web.Lists.GetByTitle(SPSite);
    CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.ViewXml= strong.Format();

    ListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(camlQuery);
    ctx.Load(list);
    ctx.Load(items);
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();

    foreach (ListItem listItem in items)
    {
      //this is where I am having the issues
      FieldUserValue monsys = (FieldUserValue)listItem["MonitoringSystem"];
      string msys = monsys.LookupValue;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: "loads the win form" - You have not posted the full code... Is there a try catch that's letting the error slip by?

Answer (score 0):

Try either of these:

```
FieldLookupValue monsys = (FieldLookupValue)listItem["MonitoringSystem"];
string msys = monsys.LookupValue;

var monsys = listItem["MonitoringSystem"];
string msys = monsys.LookupValue;
```

You may need to explicitly load the properties. There are several ways to do this. Not having seen the rest of your code, maybe like this:

```
context.Load(list.Fields);
```

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-client-library-code#sharepoint-field-tasks

or

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-client-library-code#retrieve-a-specific-field-from-the-list

Comment: Using your first example of FieldLookupValue I get the same result as my OP using FieldUserValue, it hits the assignment line and immediately launches the form.  If I try the second example, when I type monsys. I do not have LookupValue as an option, only Equals, GetHashCode, GetType, and ToString

Comment: I have updated the answer with notes about loading the field.

Comment: My apology see my edit for further syntax. I appreciate the help!